# Break New Line SMS Android

Tags: android

I want to break new line in SMS.

This is my code :

```
public void sendSMS()
    {
        String time;
        SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
        Calendar calendars = Calendar.getInstance();
        time = dayFormat.format(calendars.getTime());
        String phoneNumber = "xxxxxxxx";
        String message = "This SMS Was sent at : " + time + ". Ruang = " + ruang + ". Lantai = " + lantai + "nama = " + nama_mahasiswa + "No = " + noHP_orangtua;
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }
```

In String message, I want to add break new line so it would show more good looking.
Could you help me ?

Comment: standard line feed not working?

Comment: what do you mean ? i'm still newbie in java

Comment: do you mean like "here is a line break\nNow for next line"? The line break is simply `\n`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
String message = "This SMS Was sent at : " + time + ".\nRuang = " + ruang + ". Lantai = " + lantai + "nama = " + nama_mahasiswa + "No = " + noHP_orangtua;
```

The "\n" inside the string might do the trick, but I've never worked with SMS in android, so I can't be sure if it will work.